# android - event when input is active to accept text

Tags: android

I am trying to run a `Service` in background which will show something whenever an input field comes to the view (within any app, like SMS, Facebook etc), but how this can be possible I thought using

```
mImm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (mImm.isAcceptingText()) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Show Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

in my background service would do the trick, but it didn't

Comment: `Toast` will only be shown form main/UI thread. Does your service run on it?

Comment: Issue is not about the `Toast`, the `Toast` is actually displaying. The issue is How can I know if current View (From any app) has the input field accepting text so that I can display some thing. Like if you try emojidom app on Google market it shows and icon whenever we open compose window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html), although toasts should work in that scenario, a notification is more suitable and professional in that scenario (IMO).

The toast is not showing because the context you are using is not from a user interface thread.

Comment: Thanks @FOliveria, but I think you didn't understand what I wanted. I want to detect any input field from any app through my `Service` and when detected show something.